# Remove \n from python string

Tags: python, parsing, strip

I have scraped a webpage using beautiful soup. 
I'm trying to get rid of a '`\n`' character which isnt eliminated despite whatever I try.

My effort so far:

```
wr=str(loc[i-1]).strip()
wr=wr.replace(r"\[|'u|\\n","")
print(wr)
```

Output:

```
    [u'\nWong; Voon Hon (Singapore, SG
Kandasamy; Ravi (Singapore, SG
Narasimalu; Srikanth (Singapore, SG
Larsen; Gerner (Hinnerup, DK
Abeyasekera; Tusitha (Aarhus N, DK
```

How do I eliminate the [u'\n? What am I doing wrong?

The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/Q9xREXUV).

Comment: You have a single quote before `\n` and after `u` in the list

Comment: remove `'` which exists before \n

Comment: I tried, that didnt work. Please see the updated code link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the newline character (double "\"):

```
rep=["[","u'","\\n"]
for r in rep:
    wr=wr.replace(r,"")
```

This is the same as @cricket_007's answer, however, the second part from his answer does not work for me. To my knowledge, str.replace() does not support these kind of regular expression lookups.

Comment: That works! Thank you :)
So we add extra \ because \n is a special character, right?

Comment: Correct. Also, as @cricket_007 pointed out, you could also use a "raw string" representation:  r"\n"

Comment: You make a good point. I was thinking of `replace` of the `re` module

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash or use a raw string. Otherwise, it's a newline character, not a literal `\n`

Also, I don't think beautifulsoup is outputting unicode strings. You see the string representation in python as `u'blah'`

And you shouldn't need a list of elements to remove. The expression can be

```
r"\[|'u|\n"
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Two backslashes `\\n`

Comment: By your advice, I did this: wr=wr.replace(r"\[|'u|\\n","")

The result is still the same.

Comment: You don't need the two slashes with the r in front of the string.